# Using UTF-8 URLs to call nominatim.openstreetmap OSM

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, geolocation, urlencode

I want to call this URL http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q= ΠΑΡΙΣΙ&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1

where 0ΠΑΡΙΣΙ is parameter I get from a JSP,

to be sure everything is correct I even write to a file the URL

```
String urls = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(addressString.trim(), "UTF-8") + "&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1";
File fileDir = new File("c:\\temp\\testUTF-82.txt");
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
 out.append(urls);
out.flush();
out.close();

URL url = new URL(urls);

HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
uc.setRequestProperty("Accept:", "application/json");           
uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset:", "UTF-8");
uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");           
uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type:","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

        uc.connect();
```

But I got this strange error:

```
Response: '406: Not Acceptable' for url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q= %CE%A0%CE%91%CE%A1%CE%99%CE%A3%CE%99&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1'
```

That is the String in the file testUTF-82.txt:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q= %CE%A0%CE%91%CE%A1%CE%99%CE%A3%CE%99&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1

Comment: I guess in the client side is fine, because its OK writing it in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link opens well in the browser. It returns a JSON response with valid OpenStreetMap output and a HTTP 200 status code.

Your client is receiving an HTTP 406 status code. [This page](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html) gives an explanation of the status code. The indicated cause of the error is a lack of match between supported response formats on the server and acceptable response formats on the client.

The following headers are related to the acceptable response formats:

- Accept (MIME types)
- Accept-Charset (character set)
- Accept-Encoding (file formats / data encoding)
- Accept-Language (natural languages)
- Accept-Ranges: (ranges of bytes from the resource i.e. a portion of the resource)

You may try explicitely setting the following request headers:

"Accept: application/json"
"Accept-Charset: UTF-8"

Comment: I am trying it with the same result :-(

Comment: Somewhere in your script the query string `ΠΑΡΙΣΙ` is lost and replaced with a bunch of question marks (url requested: `... /search?q= ??????&format=json ...`. This does not happens when writing the URL to file, but it does happen when the writing of the URL in a file, but it does when composing the HTTP request. I would look at the `toString()` call in this segment `new String(urls.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")`